# Can't modify my heroku remote

Tags: heroku, deployment, heroku-toolbelt

I have trouble deploying ma app to heroku.

When I do `git remote -v` I have:

`heroku git@heroku.com:https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (fetch)
 heroku git@heroku.com:https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (push)`

instead of:

`heroku https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (fetch)
heroku https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (push)`

How do I remove the `git@heroku.com:` that prepends the right url ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use these commands to change heroku remote.

```
git remote rm heroku 
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
```